# understanding Microsoft Download Center naming convention

Tags: sql-server, sql

The following are the download names for SQL Server Express Editions.

- SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe
- SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe
- SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.exe

The machine I have is a 32 bit intel machine. Which one should I use?

I thought x86 is for 32 bit and x64 is for 64 bit, but there is also the 3rd version and it confuses me.

Comment: You want to use `SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe`. Of course `SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe` and `SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.exe` are actually can both be used on x86 operating systems.  Besides you should be using SQL Express 2012 instead of an earlier version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.exe` is 32 bit only. This is done to reduce the package size for ease of distribution. This means that the package can only be installed on 32 bit systems.

The `SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe` is compatible with both 32 and 64 bit systems, but is still the 32 bit version of SQL Server.

The `SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe` is compatible only with 64 bit systems.

Comment: Really? Based on Details section in SQL 2014 Express [download link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299) it is vice versa: `SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.exe` runs on both platforms. But interestingly the size is smaller then pure 32bit `SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe` package.

Answer (score 3):

SQLEXPR identifies the core edition, the addition of the 32 means that it is a 32bit only package. (We do this in order to reduce the size for deployment.) Without the 32 means it supports installing in the WoW subsystem on an x64 platform, but it's still the 32bit version of SQL Express.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2008/08/22/the-sql-express-2008-family-is-getting-bigger.aspx